# org.osgi.framework.BundleException:The Activator ..for bundle .. is invalid

Tags: java, osgi

Is this Bundle exception occurs because of changing workspace again and again?
The project which I used to run properly before is getting this exception now while running.
Please help me out. I've been stuck with this problem for 2 days.

```
      Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Project
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.spundhan.eboard.project; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.spundhan.eboard.project.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: SPUNDHAN
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.emf;bundle-version="2.6.0",
 org.eclipse.ui.console;bundle-version="3.5.100",
 org.jdom;bundle-version="1.1.1",
 org.eclipse.ui.navigator;bundle-version="3.5.101",
 org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources;bundle-version="3.4.300",
 org.eclipse.ui.views.log;bundle-version="1.0.200",
 org.eclipse.ui.ide;bundle-version="3.7.0",
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.7.101",
 org.eclipse.gef;bundle-version="3.7.2",
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore;bundle-version="2.7.0",
 org.eclipse.ui.views;bundle-version="3.6.0",
 org.eclipse.help;bundle-version="3.5.100",
 org.eclipse.help.ui;bundle-version="3.5.101",
 org.eclipse.ui.forms;bundle-version="3.5.101",
 org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal;bundle-version="3.2.500",
 org.eclipse.help.webapp;bundle-version="3.6.1",
 org.eclipse.ui.intro;bundle-version="3.4.100",
 org.eclipse.cdt.ui;bundle-version="5.2.2";resolution:=optional,
 com.spundhan.eboard.code;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 com.spundhan.eboard.emf;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 com.spundhan.eboard.gef;bundle-version="1.0.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Import-Package: com.spundhan.eboard.gef.components.model,
 com.spundhan.eboard.gef.model,
 com.spundhan.eboard.gef.part,
 com.spundhan.eboard.model,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.jface.text,
 org.eclipse.ui.console
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 libs/com.spundhan.licensing-1.0.0.jar,
 libs/log4j-1.2.15.jar,
 libs/RXTXcomm.jar,
 libs/com.spundhan.eboard.db-1.0.0.jar,
 .,
 libs/bcpg-jdk15-143.jar,
 libs/bcprov-jdk15-143.jar
```

**Activator :**

```
package com.spundhan.eboard.project;

import org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

/**
 * The activator class controls the plug-in life cycle
 */
public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin {

    // The plug-in ID
    public static final String PLUGIN_ID = "com.spundhan.eboard.project"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    // The shared instance
    private static Activator plugin;

    /**
     * The constructor
     */
    public Activator() {
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin#start(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
     */
    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        super.start(context);
        plugin = this;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin#stop(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
     */
    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        plugin = null;
        super.stop(context);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the shared instance
     *
     * @return the shared instance
     */
    public static Activator getDefault() {
        return plugin;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an image descriptor for the image file at the given
     * plug-in relative path
     *
     * @param path the path
     * @return the image descriptor
     */
    public static ImageDescriptor getImageDescriptor(String path) {
        return imageDescriptorFromPlugin(PLUGIN_ID, path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball is defect. We need much more information! Show us your manifest and the activator code. If it is a problem with the IDE (changeing workspaces) did you tried to rebuild everything? (E.g. using maven, try mvn eclipse:eclipse to rebuild the project if you are using eclipse)

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: org.osgi.framework.BundleException..Its saying that Activator is invalid

Comment: I'll try again. What is the full error message. Cut and paste it.

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution that worked *for me*. Each error is different, but let's see if you are lucky.

Open the manifest and go to the Build tab. In runtime configuration, if nothing appears, click on "Add library" and then just write a point "**.**". Then, add the **src/** to the runtime folders.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, take a look to the build.properties file to see if everything's correct regarding to source.

Comment: Try to clean the project first (Project-> Clean), and also mark "Clear the configuration area before launching" option on the settings tab inside Run Configurations option.

Comment: I'm not getting setting tab inside Run Configuration!

Comment: Why is src on the Bundle-ClassPath? Pure cargo cult development practices... hilarious.

Comment: please tel me where will be settins tab in Run configurations

Comment: You should create a new Osgi Run Configuration (right click->add)